# Problems when preservedRouteParameters contains UrlParameter.Optional

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This issue bother me hours. Here is my routes.MapRoute:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "SiteArea",
            "SiteArea/{area}/{link}",
            new { controller = "SiteArea", action = "Dispatch", link = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces
        );
```

The link is optional, could be null. In Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="SiteArea" controller="SiteArea" action="Dispatch" route="SiteArea" preservedRouteParameters="area,link" />
```

In C# Mvc action:

```
public override ActionResult Dispatch(string area, string link)
    {
        var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.ParentNode.Title = area;
            node.Title = link;
        }

        return base.Dispatch(area, link);
    }
```

The

> SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode

always throw exception:

```
 The node with key _Home_Index_GET_Home__SiteArea_Dispatch_GET_SiteArea_' and title 'SiteArea' has 'area' configured in both RouteValues and PreservedRouteParameters, which is not allowed. PreservedRouteParameters copies the route value from the current HTTP request which would overwrite your configured RouteValue in every case. Either remove 'area' from PreservedRouteParameters or as a configured RouteValue.
    Alternatively, if you are configuring the node in XML and intend to use 'area' as a custom attribute, use the 'MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore' configuration setting to ensure 'area' is not automatically added to RouteValues. If using external DI, this setting is injected into the constructor of 'SiteMapXmlReservedAttributeNameProvider'.
```

I know this exception is bogus one and won't tell anything useful to this issue.
However, I have exactly same situtation except the link is not UrlParameter.Optional - not nullable and it worked fine.
Can anyone explain or provide solution to this issue - when the second preserved parameter is optional?

Answer (score 1):

`area` is a reserved route value in `MvcSiteMapProvider` in case your project is using MVC areas. If you are not using MVC areas, there is still an automatic route value used as a default area (`area = ""`).

So, you need to change your route key to another name other than `area`. Otherwise this value cannot be placed into `preservedRouteParameters` due to this conflict.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "SiteArea",
        "SiteArea/{myArea}/{link}",
        new { controller = "SiteArea", action = "Dispatch", link = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces
    );

<mvcSiteMapNode title="SiteArea" controller="SiteArea" action="Dispatch" route="SiteArea" preservedRouteParameters="myArea,link" />
```

Comment: Exactly, this is accurate and clean explanation, hopefully, no more people repeat this mistake which caused me hours to figure out,

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out the root cause of the problem. I was using area keyword in:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "SiteArea",
                "SiteArea/{area}/{link}",
                new { controller = "SiteArea", action = "Dispatch", link = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces
            );
```

and in Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="SiteArea" controller="SiteArea" action="Dispatch"  preservedRouteParameters="area" >
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="SiteArea" controller="SiteArea" action="Dispatch"  preservedRouteParameters="area,link"  />
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

After changed the

> > area to 
> >     siteArea

everything goes like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error like this and was confused as to why it happened. Before troubleshooting too much, try to run the code again.  As mysteriously as it appeared for me, it was not happening on a second, third, etc. try.